# Delete Multiple Rows Based On Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to come up with macros to clean up a report I am working on.

I would like to delete multiple rows based on one cell value. So if cell F8 contains a value greater than 100, then I'd like to delete entirety of row 8, 7, 6 & 5.

A bit of a VBA Excel newbie here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want to start from something like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete4PreceedingRows()

Dim cellsToCheck As Range, cell As Range

Set cellsToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F100") '<== set here the range address you want to scan
For Each cell In cellsToCheck
    If cell.value > 100 Then cell.EntireRow.Offset(-3).Resize(4).delete Shift:=xlUp
Next cell

End Sub
```

where `Offset()` and `Resize()` are to very useful methods of Excel `Range` object you may want to begin studying Excel VBA from (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)

Comment: This works near perfect. The only problem I have run into is I have to run it 3 or 4 times to get all the values. Might you know why? Also, thank you for the link. I am going to start reviewing it.

Answer (score 0):

try it!, just copy and paste this code on new sub VBA, when cell F8 is >100, delete rows 5,6,7 &8

```
Sub delete()

If Range("F8").Value > 100 Then
    Rows("5:8").delete Shift:=xlUp
End If

End Sub
```

[Value cell F8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7C8a.jpg)